# Percentage app for teachers not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make an application for a teacher (my mom) to calculate the grade letter and percent for a certain amount wrong of a number possible. The application crashes after I press the button on the first screen. I was wondering if someone could help me.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

int MaxInt;

private Button button;

private EditText ETmax;

private TextView TV1;
private TextView TV2;
private TextView TV3;
private TextView TV4;
private TextView TV5;
private TextView TV6;
private TextView TV7;
private TextView TV8;
private TextView TV9;
private TextView TV10;
private TextView TV11;
private TextView TV12;
private TextView TV13;
private TextView TV14;
private TextView TV15;
private TextView TV16;
private TextView TV17;
private TextView TV18;
private TextView TV19;
private TextView TV20;
private TextView TV21;
private TextView TV22;
private TextView TV23;
private TextView TV24;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);

    ETmax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    TV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TV3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TV4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TV5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TV6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    TV7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    TV8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    TV9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    TV10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    TV11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    TV12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TV13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    TV14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    TV15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    TV16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    TV17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    TV18 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
    TV19 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
    TV20 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
    TV21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    TV22 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    TV23 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
    TV24 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);

    //TV1-8 how many wrong
    //TV9-16 percentage
    //TV17-24 letter grade

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           MaxInt = Integer.parseInt(ETmax.getText().toString());
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TV1.setText(MaxInt - 1);
            TV2.setText(MaxInt - 2);
            TV3.setText(MaxInt - 3);
            TV4.setText(MaxInt - 4);
            TV5.setText(MaxInt - 5);
            TV6.setText(MaxInt - 6);
            TV7.setText(MaxInt - 7);
            TV8.setText(MaxInt - 8);
            TV9.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 1) / MaxInt) + "%");
            TV10.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 2) / MaxInt) + "%");
            TV11.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 3) / MaxInt) + "%");
            TV12.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 4) / MaxInt) + "%");
            TV13.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 5) / MaxInt) + "%");
            TV14.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 6) / MaxInt) + "%");
            TV15.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 7) / MaxInt) + "%");
            TV16.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 8) / MaxInt) + "%");


        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line from public void onClick

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and it looks like it should work for you if all you wanted to do was update the text displayed in the text views. If there were any intended layout changes you will have to start a new activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the layout by calling setContentView when the button has been clicked. If you want to change what's displayed, you need to set views visible/invisible manually, use a ViewFlipper, load a new fragment in your activity's container or load a new Activity. From your code, it looks like you may want to start a new Activity with the main_activity layout.

Comment: I am not sure that is what I am looking for. Is there any other way? @Francesc

Answer (score 0):

use this if you want to start a new activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, the_name_of_class_to_go.class);
startActivity(intent);
```